# Multiple marks in Reader

Tags: java, groovy, bufferedreader

I can't find the functionality to write the following code in Java (or Groovy)

```
reader.mark();   //(1)
reader.read();   //reads 'a'
reader.mark();   //(2)
reader.read();   //reads 'b'
reader.reset();  //back to (2)
reader.read();   //reads 'b'
reader.reset();  //back to (1)
reader.read();   //reads 'a'
reader.read();   //reads 'b'
```

`Reader.mark(int)` is a nice method but it doen't stack the marks, it only holds the most recent one..

Any support from Java library or am I on my own?

Comment: I believe that `mark` starts caching the data internally, and replays it when reset is called. that's why you have to set the buffer size before the mark is discarded

Comment: I need any method, or `Reader` implementation that supports this simple operation. C language has `ftell` and `fseek`.

Comment: You are on your own, but I like the idea. It sounds similar to a Stack

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So I wrote it myself -.-

```
class CharReader {
    private Stack marks;
    private RandomAccessFile reader;

    CharReader(File file) {
        this.marks = new Stack();
        this.reader = new RandomAccessFile(file, 'r');
    }

    void mark() {
        long mark = reader.getFilePointer();
        marks.push(mark);
    }

    void reset() {
        if (marks.size() <= 0)
            return

        long mark = marks.pop();
        reader.seek(mark);
    }

    char peek() {
        mark();
        char nextChar = next();
        reset();
        return nextChar;
    }


    char next() {
        int nextChar;
        if ((nextChar = nextInt()) >= 0) {
            return (char) nextChar;
        }
        throw new IllegalStateException("Reader empty");
    }

    private int nextInt() {
        return reader.read();
    }
}
```

It's enough for my needs. Supports only single-byte `char`s ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You might try implementing something around a [`PushBackReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PushbackReader.html), which has an `unread` method that allows you to push unwanted characters into a pushback buffer.

```
char a, b;         // reader holds "ab"
a = reader.read(); // reader holds "b"
b = reader.read(); // reader holds ""
reader.unread(b);  // reader holds "b"
b = reader.read(); // reader holds ""
reader.unread(b);  // reader holds "b"
reader.unread(a);  // reader holds "ab"
a = reader.read(); // reader holds "b"
b = reader.read(); // reader holds ""
```

For may parsing applications this sort of facility is enough to do what you need.

Another option is for each nesting layer that needs marking to construct a new `Reader` over top of the one they are passed, and mark that one instead.